# what should be the argument for sqlContext.createDataFrame()?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This code is creating dataframe from given lists:

```
sample_one = [(0, 'mouse'), (1, 'black')]
sample_two = [(0, 'cat'), (1, 'tabby'), (2, 'mouse')]
sample_three =  [(0, 'bear'), (1, 'black'), (2, 'salmon')]
sample_data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(sample_one,), (sample_two,),(sample_three,)], ['features'])
```

In createDataFrame() , why extra comma is given after sample_one(sample_one,)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is to create a tuple. You can try the following:

```
>>> sample_one = [(0, 'mouse'), (1, 'black')]
>>> type((sample_one))
<type 'list'>
>>> type((sample_one,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: @Anthony..Thanks...  And this is because we need to give a list of tuples to createDataFrame()..right?